# Proving that this algorithm distributes a quantity as expected

Tags: algebra-precalculus, algorithms, recursion, recursive-algorithms

### Background (non-essential)

Let $Q$ be an integer quantity (of say, marbles) to be distributed into $n$ buckets ($B_1$ ... $B_n$) according to weights. Let $w_1$ ... $w_n$ be the non-negative weights, *e.g.* 100, 0, 28.4, ...

The algorithm someone has proposed to do this is:

1. Find the sum of the weights: $\sum_{j=1}^n{w_j}$
2. Use the obvious formula to determine how much goes to bucket 1:
   $$B_1 = \frac{Q\cdot w_1}{\sum_{j=1}^n{w_j}}$$
3. Now, *instead of using the obvious formula for bucket 2*, reduce the quantity to discount the just-now-allocated amount, reduce the sum of the weights to de-represent the just-now-allocated bucket, and only *then* use the obvious formula:
   $$B_2 = \frac{(Q-B_1)\cdot w_2}{(\sum_{j=1}^n{w_j})-w_1}$$
4. And so on for the following buckets.

You might wonder we wouldn't just use the obvious formula for all the buckets. The quick answer is that our actual problem is a little more involved, for example needing to distribute in rounded lots (*e.g.* multiples of 100 marbles) and buckets having minimum requirements (*e.g.* at least 100 marbles, even if weight doesn't justify). This method of making a bucket "disappear" once it's been given it's marbles, somehow appears to simplify the algorithm quite a bit (compared to other two- or three-pass proposals).

But, I'm reluctant to believe it's distributing correctly, *i.e.* just as the "obvious formula" would have distributed across the buckets, until I see an algebraic equivalence. So that's what I sought to prove or disprove, and I'm having trouble.

### Question

Here's the "obvious formula":

$$B_i = \frac{Q\cdot w_i}{\sum_{j=1}^n{w_j}}$$

Here's our proposed formula (note the sum from $i$, not $1$):

$$
\hat{B}_i = \begin{cases}
B_1 & i=1 \\
\frac{(Q-\hat{B}_{(i-1)})\cdot w_i}{\sum_{j=i}^n{w_j}} & i > 1
\end{cases}
$$

Are they equivalent?

$$B_i\equiv\hat{B}_i$$

When I think of it *intuitively*, it seems absolutely correct, again, by picturing it as removing a bucket that's no longer in consideration, and appropriately adjusting the sum of the weights. But my algebraic manipulations keep ending up with growing polynomial expansions that won't simplify.

Comment: Sounds like a candidate for induction. The base case is rather trivial, since both formulas are the same ($n=2$).

Comment: Ugh. Once you said that, it made it so easy. Thanks.

Comment: No problem :D Hardly any work involved on my part. I can write this up as an answer to get the question off the unanswered list if you want.

Comment: I'm writing out my derivation as an answer actually, unless you'd like to?

Comment: If your answer is more complete, go ahead. If you only want to add a little, you can also edit my post - I don't mind :)

Comment: Added a complete answer but accepting yours :)

Comment: @AlexR - Upon trying to write out the remaining steps of the induction, I failed. Could you perhaps take a look when you get a chance and see if I've made a mistake somewhere? (Or perhaps the two formulae aren't equivalent after all...)

Comment: I've written up a proof now. It's not particularly elegant or short, but it does the job. The key idea is using a recursive induction by combining the last two weights first and then pulling them apart after equality of the first few elements has been established.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a candidate for induction. The base case is rather trivial, since both formulas are the same for $n=2$.
Proceed by using the $n=2$ and the $n=k$ case to prove the $k+1$ case.

---

WLOG assume $\sum_{k=1}^N \omega_i = 1$.
Let $Q_k := Q - \sum_{i=1}^{k-1} B_i$. We want to demonstrate that the sequences
$$B_k := \omega_k Q_k \left(\sum_{i=k}^N \omega_i\right)^{-1}$$
and
$$C_k := \omega_k Q$$
are identical.

We prove by induction on $N$, starting at the first nontrivial case $N=2$:
$$B_1 = \omega_1 Q_1 / (\omega_1 + \omega_2) = \omega_1 Q = C_1 \qquad \checkmark$$
$$B_2 = \omega_2 Q_2 / \omega_2 = Q_2 = Q - B_1 = (1-\omega_1) Q = \omega_2 Q \qquad \checkmark$$

Now assume the hypothesis holds for $n < N$. Chose $\omega'$ such that
$$\begin{align*}
\omega'_i & = \omega_i \qquad 1\le i\le N-2\\
\omega'_{N-1} & = \omega_{N-1} + \omega_N
\end{align*}$$
Since $B_k$ and $C_k$ only depend on the sum of the weigths of indices $>k$, the so generated sequences $B'_k$ and $C'_k$ coincide with $B_k$ and $C_k$ for $1\le k \le N-2$ by construction. All we need to show now is that the last elements also match.
$$B_{N-1} = \omega_{N-1} Q_{N-1}/(\omega_{N-1} + \omega_N)\\
B_N = Q_N = Q_{N-1} - B_{N-1} = (1-\frac{\omega_{N-1}}{\omega_{N-1}+\omega_N})Q_{N-1} = \omega_N Q_{N-1} /(\omega_{N-1}+\omega_N)$$
The final step is thus to show
$$Q = Q_{N-1}/(\omega_{N-1} + \omega_N)$$
This is simple, however:
$$Q_{N-1} = Q - \sum_{i=1}^{N-2} B_i \stackrel{i.H.}= Q - \sum_{i=1}^{N-2} \omega_i Q = Q\left(1-\sum_{i=1}^{N-2} \omega_i\right) = Q(\omega_{N-1}+\omega_N)$$
Q.E.D.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT: I thought I proved this by induction but upon writing things out I realize I can't. Can someone point out if I'm making an algebraic error somewhere?**

---

As per @AlexR's suggestions, here I show

\begin{align}
B_i=\hat{B}_i
\end{align}

by induction. The case of $i=1$ is already given by definition. We show the truth of the case $i=2$ as the basis step for induction:

\begin{align}
B_2&=\hat{B}_2\\
\frac{Q\cdot w_2}{\sum_{j=1}^n{w_j}}&=\frac{\left(Q-\hat{B}_{(2-1)}\right)\cdot w_2}{\sum_{j=2}^n{w_j}}\\
\frac{Q\cdot w_2}{\sum_{j=1}^n{w_j}}&=\frac{\left(Q-\frac{Q\cdot w_1}{\sum_{j=1}^n{w_j}}\right)\cdot w_2}{\sum_{j=2}^n{w_j}}\\
\frac{Q\cdot w_2}{\sum_{j=1}^n{w_j}}&=\left(1-\frac{w_1}{\sum_{j=1}^n{w_j}}\right)\frac{Q\cdot w_2}{\sum_{j=2}^n{w_j}}\\
\frac{1}{\sum_{j=1}^n{w_j}}&=\left(1-\frac{w_1}{\sum_{j=1}^n{w_j}}\right)\frac{1}{\sum_{j=1}^n{w_j}-w_1}\\
\frac{\sum_{j=1}^n{w_j}-w_1}{\sum_{j=1}^n{w_j}}&=\left(1-\frac{w_1}{\sum_{j=1}^n{w_j}}\right)\\
1-\frac{w_1}{\sum_{j=1}^n{w_j}}&=\left(1-\frac{w_1}{\sum_{j=1}^n{w_j}}\right)
\end{align}

Finally, we assume the case to be true for $i=k$ and show the case for $i=k+1$ to also be true:

\begin{align}
B_{k+1}&=\hat{B}_{k+1}\\
\frac{Q\cdot w_{k+1}}{\sum_{j=1}^n{w_j}}&=\frac{\left(Q-\hat{B}_{(k)}\right)\cdot w_{k+1}}{\sum_{j=k+1}^n{w_j}}\\
\frac{Q\cdot w_{k+1}}{\sum_{j=1}^n{w_j}}&=\frac{\left(Q-\frac{Q\cdot w_k}{\sum_{j=1}^n{w_j}}\right)\cdot w_{k+1}}{\sum_{j=k+1}^n{w_j}}\\
\frac{Q\cdot w_{k+1}}{\sum_{j=1}^n{w_j}}&=\left(1-\frac{w_k}{\sum_{j=1}^n{w_j}}\right)\frac{Q\cdot w_{k+1}}{\sum_{j={k+1}}^n{w_j}}\\
\frac{1}{\sum_{j=1}^n{w_j}}&=\left(1-\frac{w_k}{\sum_{j=1}^n{w_j}}\right)\frac{1}{\sum_{j=1}^n{w_j}-\sum_{j=1}^k{w_j}}\\
\frac{\sum_{j=1}^n{w_j}-\sum_{j=1}^k{w_j}}{\sum_{j=1}^n{w_j}}&=\left(1-\frac{w_k}{\sum_{j=1}^n{w_j}}\right)\\
1-\frac{\sum_{j=1}^k{w_j}}{\sum_{j=1}^n{w_j}}&\not=\left(1-\frac{w_k}{\sum_{j=1}^n{w_j}}\right)
\end{align}